# Catching SQL unique key exceptions in .NET

Tags: .net, asp.net, sql

I was wondering if anyone had a more elegant way to check for unique key exceptions from SQL in .NET other than parsing the error message?  Right now I am calling the sproc in SQL, then using a try catch block in .NET.  In the try catch block I parse the error message and it is a Unique key error I throw an instance of a custom error to the calling class, if not I just throw the original exception the the calling class.  This seems awfully inefficient to me.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

If you catch a SqlException, you should be able to enumerate the "Errors" collection holding a number of "SqlError" objects.

The SqlError has among other things properties like "Class" and "Number" - unique key violations are class = 14 and number = 2601. Check for those numbers to find your error precisely.

Those are the same error codes you get when you try to execute the query in SQL Management Studio:

> Msg 2601, Level 14, State 1, Line 1
>   Cannot insert duplicate key row in
>   object ..........
>   The statement has been terminated.

The "Msg" translates to the "Number" property on SqlError, the "Level" to "Class".

```
try
{
  _cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch(SqlException sqlExc)
{
   foreach (SqlError error in sqlExc.Errors)
   {
      string msg = string.Format("{0}: {1}", error.Number, error.Message);
   }
}
```

That way, you can easily and EXACTLY identify a "unique constraint violated" error.

Marc

Comment: I think checking for "number" (without class) is sufficient. The "class" seems to only tell the severity.

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just query if the unique id exists ? 
It's better then getting exception.

Comment: +1 for avoiding the exception in the first place.  Your stored proc should check for existence and return a well-known result if the key already exists, in which case you can handle without throwing an exception, which is much more efficient.

Comment: Unless you make your stored procedure Serializable, aren't you going to run into concurrency issues as the number of transactions per second increase? In other words, between your checking that the row does not exist and inserting it, another user has already inserted the row. Not to mention the overhead of doing the check in the first place. IMHO it's much better to just insert and handle the error from .NET.

Answer (score 2):

Parsing error message is bad idea. For example if you are using Ms SQL message can be localized (in different language) and you will not find word that you are looking for.

If you are using Ms SQL you should check [Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number(VS.71).aspx) property.

Comment: What annoys me about this is that SQL Server doesn't distinguish between a primary key violation and a unique constraint violation when it comes to error codes, as they both return 2627. A unique index violation returns 2601, but most times I'm using PKs or UCs. Any thoughts on how to tell a PK violation from a UC violation in a localisation-safe way?

Answer (score 1):

Obvious answer:  Attempt to fetch that value from the database before inserting (or updating) it and notify the user before you do the insert.

Alternative answer: Check for the uniqueness inside the SP and return that as an error message from the SP, then you don't have to parse any errors.  They're all bad.