# C# LINQ - Recognize unique index violation

Tags: linq, sql-server-2008

I am using Linq-to-SQL for accessing SQL Server 2008.
In database I have UNIQUE index on some column.

When I enter duplicated data in that column, LINQ will throw SqlException with an error message. Is there a way to figure out that exception is related to UNIQUE index and not some other SQL error?

Solution I am aware of is to user RegEx to parse exception message, but I would like to know is there more elegant approach?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [`SQLException.Number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.number.aspx) property.

For more details you could iterate the [`Errors`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.errors.aspx) collection each of which have thier own [`number`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlerror.number.aspx).

---

As an aside, in the past I have written my own custom serialiser for `SqlException` but it appears that in 4.5 [`ToString()`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.sqlclient.sqlexception.tostring.aspx) has been overridden so this is not now necessary.

Comment: SqlException.Number property is solution but list you provided didn't contain appropriate number. Unique key violation number is 2601. More information about this can be found at  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/628189/catching-sql-unique-key-exceptions-in-net

Comment: I must admit, in practice I make the exception I'm interested in catching occur that debug the exception to find some distinguishing property. Apologies, I didn't actually download that list, I've removed from my answer.

Answer (score 1):

You could check the table having the unique constraint on whether it already has a row with some value in the constrained column:

```
            if (linqDataContext.ConstrainedTable.Any(row => row.ConstrainedColumn == somevalue))
            {
                //show a message, saying you've already got this value
                //and it is not applicable    
            }
            else
            {
                //accept your changes with smth like this:
                linqDataContext.SubmitChanges();
            }
```

Another question, whether this approach is applicable for you, i.e. whether the cost of this query overwhelms the cost of catching an exception and processing it. If the constrained column is indexed, than a simple request on that column must not be that costy.